# Why do we need to cast the object returned by the Parse method?

Tags: c#

I am learning to convert a string to an enumeration using the code below:

```
var methodName = "Express";
var shippingMethod = (ShippingMethod)Enum.Parse(typeof(ShippingMethod), methodName);
```

where the enum is defined as follows:

```
public enum ShippingMethod
{
    RegularAirMail = 1,
    RegisteredAirMail = 2,
    Express = 3
}
```

I am really confused about why we need to cast the object returned by `Enum.Parse(typeof(ShippingMethod), methodName)` using `(ShippingMethod)`.

Since what `Enum.Parse(typeof(ShippingMethod), methodName)` returns is already an object of type enumType (in our code this is `ShippingMethod`) whose value is the value of `methodName`, may I ask how this object is different from what it is after being casted to `ShippingMethod`?

Many thanks!

Comment: You are calling the [non-generic `Enum.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse?view=net-5.0#System_Enum_Parse_System_Type_System_String_). It returns an `object`. As far as *your* code is concerned, that `object` can be anything. So you cast it to the actual type to tell *your* code what it actually is. If you don't like the casting, use the [generic overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse?view=net-5.0#System_Enum_Parse__1_System_String_).

Comment: @GSerg Hi, thank you for your comment, I'm new to C# and could you please explain more on what you meant by "that ```object``` can be anything"? Since this object is already of type ```ShippingMethod```, why it can be anything?

Comment: C# is a statically typed language. The method returns `object` and, at compile time, the compiler has no idea that that `object` is actually holding a `ShippingMethod` as a result of calling `Parse`.

Comment: @Llama Thank you for commenting, so can I understand it as what is returned by the method is already of type ```ShippingMethod``` whose value is ```methodName```, but it is **represented** by ```object``` so that to some extent the compiler cannot "see" what's inside the ```object```, and thus we need to explicitly tell the compiler about it. May I ask if I'm on the right track?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You could also tell the compiler that it's a string, but you'd get a runtime exception because it isn't: `(string)Enum.Parse(typeof(ShippingMethod), methodName);` so essentially you're saying "I know what I'm doing and I know what type this returns."

Comment: @Llama Thanks a lot, I forgot ```object``` is a standalone thing that we can use. That makes more sense now. May I further ask why would ```Enum.Parse(...)``` be designed to return ```object``` rather than the actual thing? Is there a benefit not letting the compiler know it immediately?

Comment: I would love to know the answer to that one too. As Amal says, as of .NET Standard 2.1 there is a generic method now too.

Comment: @J-A-S Because previously there was no generics in C#. Now that there are generics, you can use the generic overload like I [have noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68242556/why-do-we-need-to-cast-the-object-returned-by-the-parse-method#comment120609353_68242556). The non-generic overload also gives you the flexibility of passing a pre-existing instance of `Type` which you cannot do with generics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the non-generic `Enum.Parse(Type type, methodName)` parses the enum and converts it to the correct enum type, if you look at the signature of the method, it is:

```
public static object Parse (Type enumType, string value);
```

As the return type is `object`, the enum is upcast to type `object`. This is because that was how the method was defined so that it could return any enum type since all types in C# are convertible to `object`.

---

However, for compile-time/static type safety, it is recommended to use the generic version of the method which is:

```
public static TEnum Parse<TEnum> (string value) where TEnum : struct;
```

This method uses generics and hence will return the correct enum type without an upcast. You can call this method like this:

```
var shippingMethod = Enum.Parse<ShippingMethod>(methodName);
```

Calling this generic version of the method ensures compile time type-safety and does not introduce a cast that could potentially fail at runtime.

---

There is also another method called `Enum.TryParse()`:

```
public static bool TryParse<TEnum> (string? value, out TEnum result) where TEnum : struct;
```

This may be preferable instead of the `Parse()` method since if the parsing fails i.e. the string is invalid, `TryParse()` will not throw an exception like `Parse`, it will just return `false`. You can use it like this:

```
bool succeeded = Enum.TryParse(methodName, out ShippingMethod shippingMethod)
```

`succeeded` will contain `true` if the parse succeeded which means you can use the `shippingMethod` variable. However, if `succeeded` is `false`, it means the string was invalid and `shippingMethod` will contain the default value of `ShippingMethod`. You can use `succeeded` to proceed only if the parsing succeeds:

```
if (succeeded)
{
    //Use shippingMethod
}
else 
{
   Console.WriteLine("Invalid string");
}
```

You might have also noticed, `TryParse` does not require a `<ShippingMethod>` type argument as it will be inferred from the type of the second parameter `out ShippingMethod`.